# How would I connect to an Access database table from a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, windows, ms-access

Basically the short story is we have a report generator running on a MySQL database at work and management wants me to modify things so we can connect to tables in an external Access database from this report generator as well.  And then create reports that join tables from the MySQL database to the Access database.  I suggested exporting the data from Access and importing it into MySQL but they want a live, real-time connection.  To complicate things further these are both on different servers right now (MySQL on Linux, Access on Windows) and I'm not sure that can be changed.

I tried to look this up online but all I could find is ways to connect to MySQL from Access, not the reverse.

Is what we are trying to do even possible, and if so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is a design idea that is just fraught with evil. And that evil is spelled A-C-C-E-S-S.

Comment: That's kind of what I said but you know... unfortunately I'm not in charge here.  I even suggested that I could rebuild the entire ASP / Access application in PHP / MySQL for them but apparently it is huge and would take at least a month or so and this is urgent and yada yada.

Comment: You want to connect the MySQL *server* to an Access database? Not going to happen. If you want to write a script that connects simultaneously to Access and MySQL, that's doable, but you haven't given any hints as to how that might play out. Python? Ruby? PHP? Node.js? C#? All could do it.

Comment: Isn't it just a case of setting the correct connection string for each database & ensuring the correct SQL syntax for the queries.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to create a function in the access file to export to a linked MySQL table, and then have the reporting system run that automatically before every report.